# Is there such a thing as a release version for Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, release, object-detection, object-detection-api

I would like to update my old version of the Tensorflow Object Detection API repository, to use some new features, like the [RetinaNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection#july-13-2018). The README states, that there has been a 'release' on July 13th, but I can neither find a tag, nor a commit, which would constitute a version, that is known to work.

Obviously `master` branch contains bleeding-edge changes, but I've tried [other commits](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/70b176a9193859a53354fbbdbdef8624932cd0d3) as well but was never able to run a simple training, without getting syntax errors in Python 3 (e.g., `print` without paranthesis, use of xrange), incorrect import statements or TF crashs due to incorrect shape dimensions somewhere down the road, e.g.,

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 100], but got 508
     [[Node: Slice_4 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](unstack_2, PadOrClipBoxList/zeros_1, stack_4)]]
     [[Node: gradients/FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_50/resnet_v1_50/block3/unit_6/bottleneck_v1/conv3/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput/_7800 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4351_...kpropInput", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Can anyone point me to a version of the repository, which contains the RetinaNet feature and is 'stable' in the sense, that you can run it without fixing syntax errors first?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the issues should have been fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/5026#issuecomment-411389269). I'm also going over the whole object detection dir to fix python 3 compatibility issues. They will be released soon!